# Is the Google Earth browser plugin available in Google Earth Enterprise Version 5.x

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

and if so, how do I find out how it differs from the current version (7.x)?  Is there a way to get API documentation for old versions of the plugin?

We have a customer with what they claim might be a 5.x deployment of Google Earth Enterprise.  We are attempting to develop a solution using the browser plugin, but dont have ready access to their deployment (it is on a secure network), and none of the personnel we have access to seem to know anything about the deployment other than it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this type of product support question is better suited for the Google forums than StackOverflow.

That said, existing enterprise customers can contact file a support case, and request an older version (only current and last versions are officially supported).

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected that was the appropriate place and I did post the same question there, but have not received a response. (https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-earth-browser-plugin/vM0PLl1bHLs/discussion).